# Avoid using multiple layouts in an item of listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, optimization, android-linearlayout

I have a listview and
 in my listview each item of listview is designed in such a way that two items are vertically arranged on left ,two items are vertically arranged in right, and two items are vertically arranged in between.Now i have designed layout for this but it took me three internal layouts to make it.Can i avoid using multiple layouts in this situation as it might effect the performance?Please note that my first linearlayout has background.Below is the code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp16"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp16"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp16"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp16">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_date"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp5"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp15"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp15"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp5"

            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp16" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp5"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp15"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp15"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp5"

            android:textColor="@color/greytext"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp16" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp12"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp5"

            android:textColor="@color/greytext"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp16" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp2"

            android:textColor="@color/greytext"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp16" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eyn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp5"

            android:textColor="@color/greytext"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp16" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp2"
            android:singleLine="true"

            android:textColor="@color/greytext"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp16" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing would be much flatter if you used a TableLayout. You can find a decent tutorial of how to make use of one [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_table_layout.htm). That would allow you do to it all within one view group, instead of the four you are currently using.

RelativeLayout would also be a good choice, if you wanted to allow each row or column to have different sizes (But I don't think you want that looking at your code).

Comment: In TableLayout,TableRow extends LinearLayout only.So whts advantage of using TableLayout here?There also we will be using four layouts as TableRow extends LinearLayout..